# What is the Ruby on Rails naming convention for models/controllers that are parts of another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure about the naming convention for objects that are related/parts of an object in Ruby on Rails.  Heres an example of this:

I have a `User` object

I have a separate `Image` model that only stores images of the `User` object

I also have a separate `History` model that only stores the actions of the `User`

Would it follow Rails convention to name them to `UserImage` and `UserHistory` models? Or is this not following convention?  If so, why not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It generally depends on what other names are used in your application, and to some degree on personal preference.

My preference is not to add namespace prefixes unless it's really necessary because of namespace collisions, or is confusing because of similarly named structures with my application. Also it is more of a rails convention to use suffixes to prevent naming collisions with classes in different areas. For example controllers are all suffixed with `Controller`, mailers suffixed with `Mailer`, decorators with `Decorator` and so on.

In your case I would stick with User, Image and History. Prefixing Image and History doesn't really gain you anything, unless you have other types of Image/History models, in which case it might be better to look into polymorphic relationships instead of namespace prefixes.

It's mostly a matter of style and maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

If you name your models this way then you will not be able to develop associations between models. Ex. UserImage model will be considered as a single entity not association of  user and image model. If you want to develop this type of associations use HABTM relationship. Thats why rails follow "Convention over configuration".

Comment: Associations can still be added. A `User` can still have `has_many :user_images` and access them with `@user.user_images`. It doesn't affect associations at all.